# checkSelfPermission is not working properly

Tags: android, android-studio, android-bluetooth

I'm trying to do a quick test app that allow me to turn on a off Bluetooth and I code the listeners for clicks in the buttons. This is the one that turn Bluetooth on:

```
mOnBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (!mBlueAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                showToast("Turning On Bluetooth...");
                //intent to on BT
                Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                //Android Studio force me to do this check.
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    showToast("I'm stuck here");
                    return;
                }
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
            } else {
                showToast("Bluetooth is already on");
            }
        }
    });
```

The thing is that Android Studio force me to add the:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    showToast("I'm stuck here");
                    return;
                }
```

check error but even I have all the permissions they asked me in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Bluetooth">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

the program always fails the check error and ended up in the "You're stuck message", what is happening here?

Answer (score 1):

Turning bluetooth on and requesting `BLUETOOTH_CONNECT permission is a different thing.

Request permission like `BLUETOOTH_CONNECT`, see https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.

Turning bluetooth on

```
if (bluetoothAdapter?.isEnabled == false) {
  val enableBtIntent = Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE)
  startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT)
}
```

> If enabling Bluetooth succeeds, your activity receives the RESULT_OK result code in the onActivityResult() callback. If Bluetooth was not enabled due to an error (or the user responded "Deny") then the result code is RESULT_CANCELED.

See [Set up Bluetooth](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/setup) for details.

Comment: But Android Studio doesn't let me write just that to turn on Bluetooth, it forces me to write a check error with checkSelfPermission().

Comment: Hello. Isnt this something that could be bypassed with `@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")` before the function if it working for all other intents..?